# QGIS 1.8 and Shapefile units in seconds

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, units

I have QGIS 1.8 on Centos 6.5 (I cannot update this system).

I have a problem with opening a shapefile layer with units in seconds (created in ERDAS).

QGIS doesn't display and doesn't save document in the "Degrees, Minutes, Seconds" option when I set it.

[image: project properties]

What am I doing wrong and how should I work with this layers?